# Putting PHP array into MySQL with additional columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about PHP arrays and inserting them as single records into a MySQL database. I have the array sorted and that is working as it should.

This is what I have for the array:

```
$files = array();
            foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
            {
                $files[$key] = array
                (
                    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key],
                    $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'][$key],
                    $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'][$key],
                    $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key]                        
                );
            }
```

This is what I have for the array to insert them as separate rows in to the database:

```
$new = array();
            foreach($files as $key => $value)
            {
                $new[] = "'".implode("','", $value)."'";
            }
            $query = "(".implode("), (",$new).")";
            $sqlone = "INSERT INTO files (filename, filetype, filesize, filetempname) VALUES ".$query."";
            if (!mysql_query($sqlone, $conn))
            {
                die("Error: " . mysql_error().".");
            }
```

The issue I am running into is this: I want to add extra information to the query but I am not entirely sure how to do this.

I want to be able to add a reference to the email that the files were attached to. I basically want the query to be as follows:

```
$sqlone = "INSERT INTO files (filename, filetype, filesize, filetempname, mailid //this is the extra column in the database) VALUES ".$query.", '1'// this is the corresponding value";
```

The issue I am running in to is that I get an error when trying to add extra information to it.

Are there any pointers you guys could give me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks correct. What error are you getting? I'd really suggest getting away from the mysql_* functions as they're deprecated and won't work in future releases. Check into PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: @aynber This is the error I am getting: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1.

I will look into using mysqli, I am just trying to get this working for now

Comment: Echo out $sqlone before you run the mysql_query to make sure it looks correct.

Comment: @aynber, I have figured out that it is not adding the mailid value to the query in the right place. I have now added it to $query = "(".implode("), (",$new).", '1' //added here)"; and it now only adds it to the last item in the array. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: You're adding it to the very end of the query. Put it in the new[] array inside of the foreach instead.

Comment: I have got it sorted. I have figured out where to place it in the query. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just change where your parenthesis is added (and quote your inputs):

```
$query = "('".implode("'), ('",$new);
$sqlone = "INSERT INTO files (filename, filetype, filesize, filetempname, mailid) VALUES ".$query."', '1')";
```

Should result in the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO files (filename, filetype, filesize, filetempname, mailid) VALUES
('<file_name>', '<file_type>', '<file_size>', '<file_tmp_name>', '1')
```