# Issues putting files into the correct folder

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

I just had another question to follow on from: [Putting PHP array into MySQL with additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073341/putting-php-array-into-mysql-with-additional-columns/17073559?noredirect=1#17073559)

I am trying to put the files into separate folders depending on the extension. However, the files end up in the same folder with the same file name regardless of what the array shows when I print it out.

This is the array that I have at the moment:

```
$files[$key] = array
(
    $file_name = basename($guid." - ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$key]),
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$key],
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$key],
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],
    $extension = strtolower(substr($file_name, strlen($file_name)-4, strlen($file_name))),
    $tgt = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key]
);
```

This is the array output I have at the moment:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 966c5853-63b4-4570-a3ee-bd5629688038 - cycles.pdf
        [1] => application/pdf
        [2] => 331881
        [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9738.tmp
        [4] => .pdf
        [5] => cycles.pdf
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 966c5853-63b4-4570-a3ee-bd5629688038 - landofstoopid.bmp
        [1] => image/bmp
        [2] => 310342
        [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9758.tmp
        [4] => .bmp
        [5] => landofstoopid.bmp
    )
```

)

This is the SQL query generation that I have:

```
$new = array();
foreach($files as $key => $value)
{
    $new[] = "'".implode("','", $value)."', '$guid', '$getthedate', '$gettime', '$mailid', '$target'";
}
$query = "(".implode("), (",$new).")";
```

This is the output from the SQL query

```
INSERT INTO files (filename, filetype, filesize, filetempname, guid, dateadded, timeadded, mailid, target) 
VALUES ('966c5853-63b4-4570-a3ee-bd5629688038 - cycles.pdf','application/pdf','331881','C:\xampp\tmp\php9738.tmp','.pdf','cycles.pdf', '966c5853-63b4-4570-a3ee-bd5629688038', '13 Jun 2013', '10:25:07', '77', 'files/pics/landofstoopid.bmp'), 
('966c5853-63b4-4570-a3ee-bd5629688038 - landofstoopid.bmp','image/bmp','310342','C:\xampp\tmp\php9758.tmp','.bmp','landofstoopid.bmp', '966c5853-63b4-4570-a3ee-bd5629688038', '13 Jun 2013', '10:25:07', '77', 'files/pics/landofstoopid.bmp')
```

This is what I have to determine where the file should be placed

```
$pics = array(".bmp", ".gif", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".png"); //5              
$docs = array(".doc", "docx", ".odt", ".pdf", ".ppt", "pptx", ".rtf", ".txt", ".xls", "xlsx"); //10             
$misc = array(".csv", ".htm", "html", ".php", ".pkt", ".rar", ".sql", ".xpi", ".zip"); //9

if (in_array($extension,$pics))
{
    $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_PICS."/";
}
else if (in_array($extension,$docs))
{
    $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_DOCS."/";
}
else if (in_array($extension,$misc))
{
    $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_MISC."/";
}
$target = $target.$tgt;
```

I have tried this both inside the foreach loop to get the values of the multiple files and outside of it and it ends up the same way.

The target for the files is always determined on the last filename and extension. As above, I have a .pdf and a .bmp and the pdf should go in the docs folder and the bmp should go in the pics folder. However, both files are being sent to pics folder and the name changed to the last file in the array.

Just wondering if I could get some pointers as to where I am going wrong, or if this is even possible.

I will add, that when the file is uploaded as a single file this issue does not occur and the file goes to the right folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing I see is: `strtolower(substr($file_name, strlen($file_name)-4, strlen($file_name)))` will not work with 4-letter-extensions... it won't give you something you can match...

Comment: Hi zero0, it does work, it just doesn't include the . For a word file for example: 97 - 2003 it will get .doc for 2010 + it will get docx and the arrays reflect this. If you look in the docs array it has .doc and docx to take into account 4 letter extensions

Comment: sorry, @Chris, I looked over the missing dot in your 4-letter array elements :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to select which folder to place files in works, though you probably ought to have a default action for unrecognised extensions.

As everything seems to be in order here, it is most likely that the problem is elsewhere.

The structure of your sql leads me to suspect that you are not changing the target between sql-generation code iterations.  Are you sure you have spelled your variable names correctly?  Is it always the extension and name of the last file that gets used? This looks like a retained-variable problem to me.

Consider deleting the code to determine where you put the file and replacing it with a function vis:

```
function set_target($extension)
    {
    $target="";
    $pics = array(".bmp", ".gif", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".png"); //5              
    $docs = array(".doc", "docx", ".odt", ".pdf", ".ppt", "pptx", ".rtf", ".txt", ".xls", "xlsx"); //10             
    $misc = array(".csv", ".htm", "html", ".php", ".pkt", ".rar", ".sql", ".xpi", ".zip"); //9

    if (in_array($extension,$pics))
        {
        $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_PICS."/";
        }
        else if (in_array($extension,$docs))
        {
        $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_DOCS."/";
        }
        else if (in_array($extension,$misc))
        {
        $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_MISC."/";
        }
    $target = $target.$tgt;
    echo $target."<BR>"; //this line for debugging - should see as many lines as you have files.  If not, the problem is in your iteration loop.
    return($target);
    }
```

Instead of the inline code.  This may help reveal the place where the target is not being correctly assigned and is good practice anyway.

Alternatively, don't try to make a single SQL query and simply produce a new SQL for each file.

If you provide the rest of the code, you may be able to get a more complete answer, but my guess is that this will fix it.  The bit that generates your sql would be useful.

Comment: Hi Robert,

This is what I have for my sql generation

$new = array();
      $mailid = '77';
      
      foreach($files as $key => $value)
    {
     $new[] = "'".implode("','", $value)."', '$guid', '$getthedate', '$gettime', '$mailid', '$target'";
    }
    $query = "(".implode("), (",$new).")";
    $sqlone = "INSERT INTO files (filename, filetype, filesize, filetempname, guid, dateadded, timeadded, mailid, target) VALUES ".$query."";

I will certainly give the function a try to see if it will solve the issue. Thanks for answering

Comment: Robert,

I am trying your function, but nothing is being returned from $target. I'm probably going wrong somewhere here. Do you have any more pointers? Cheers

Comment: I have cut and pasted the code and tested the function again.  It does return the target correctly.  Try a call with fixed value thus: echo set_target(".bmp"); and see if you get a result.   The extra code above still doesn't include a reset of the target value though - you have to call the function WITHIN the foreach loop.  Got to work now but if you're still stuck later I'll post some of my own code that does much the same thing...

Comment: Hi Robert, I have tried the following:

Echoing out set_target(".bmp"); at the end of the forloop, but before the last curly brace - this doesn't echo anything.

Adding $file_target -> set_target($extension) to the array, but this gives me the following error:

'Call to undefined function set_target()' and also 'Call to a member function set_target() on a non-object' when it is outside of the array but still in the forloop

I just don't know where I am going wrong. I feel it is something so simple but can't figure it out. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Ok - patient gone for urine specimen...  The OOP -> method won't work for this function as it is not in a class.  try echo "YAY"; next to the function call.  If this works, check the function is correctly copied.  I cut and pasted it directly from the code above and it worked fine this morning.  Get back to me...

Comment: My apologies for sounding dumb. Am I echoing the yay after the function. I'm just not quite sure where to put this. Inside the function I have echo "Target: ".$target."<BR>"; and it is echoing out the Target and <br> just not $target. Obviously the echo won't work inside the array and if I put it outside as follows: echo "YAY".set_target() I get undefined function error

Comment: So, i've managed to get it to echo a target. When I have more than one file it obviously cannot redeclare the function. Do you have any advice on how to overcome this? Cheers for all your help so far

Comment: So, i've managed to get round the redeclare by using if(!function_exists

I, however, cannot for the life of me get the set_target($extension) in the array to show the target. Is this just something that is not possible?

Comment: Nope.  Wrong way.  In a rush right now between victims - I think you are misunderstanding the use of functions.  the syntax would be:  $target=set_target($extension) and you put this line in just before where you generate $query.  If that doesn't work, I'll post a better way of writing this code in a few hours (really have to work!)

Comment: I get how the function works. It will just not allow it to be called unless I use if(!function_exists). It just says I cannot redeclare it. I have got it working as it should be. Thank you again for all of your help. It has been really useful

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing.  Put the function at the TOP of your code, after your first <?PHP NOT in the middle.  that should fix it...